# Eclipse Python Al definir (def) me sale error de sintaxis

Tags: python, eclipse

Al usar def me sale este error(Encountered "def" at line 140, column 1. Was expecting one of:...)
cuando en las otras def no me salen error, solo me sale ahí y al ejecutarlo me sale error de sintaxis, puede ser error del interpreter y tal pero ni idea. Alguna solucion?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo, que error de sintaxis te aparece¿ Tal vez te falte cerrar algo, tendrias que revisar bien

Comment: Me sale justo esto: def filtra_paises_ano (poblaciones, anyo, paises):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: y si borro esa parte del codigo me sale el error : SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Debiste haber omitido un parentesis o algo

Comment: Sisi ya está solucionado, fue un parentesis. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido, @Chema. Para otras preguntas parecidas, no pegues imágenes. Coloca el texto del programa.... y del error. Y coloca más líneas del código en cuestión para tener un contexto de lo que está pasando. Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto.